# Specify fields you want on FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have an object that takes the information from a rest API. Let's say I call Posts from an API and I can specify which fields I want to extract. Just an example of how it looks:

```
Post.find!(id: 1, fields: [:id, :title, :description])
```

This does an API call and it returns me a Post object with these specified fields.

For testing, I am stubbing this API call with Factory Bot and returns directly a Post object with all possible fields it can query.

This approach is not the best since the tests are always returning all fields and code itself maybe I just need a couple of fields not all of them

So I am trying to achieve something like (in FactoryBot):

`build(:post, fields: [:id,:title])` and set up a Post object just with id and title.

If I do `build(:post, fields: [:title, :created_at])` and set up a Post object just with title and created_at. And so on...

Did some research and trying some ideas,  but failed in all of them about how to build this flow.

Any idea about how to achieve this behavior?

**EDIT**
Traits seems a nice alternative, but I must be as consistent as the API call, specifying these `fields`. So traits are not working for me...

Comment: never used FactoryBot, but can't you use something like select?
`Post.select(:id, :title).find!(id: 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: If what you are testing is actually the client that transforms JSON into models you should be stubbing the HTTP call with something like Webmock. I would only use FactoryBot if you want to fake out the entire interaction and just get an array of records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that this is your factory for the Post:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Post no. #{n}" }
    description 'Post description'
    created_at { DateTime.now }
  end
end
```

When you call `build(:post)` it will create an object with title, created_at and description set.

But if you will remove those fields from your factory (or move them under trait):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do

    trait :all_fields do
      sequence(:title) { |n| "Post no. #{n}" }
      description 'Post description'
      created_at { DateTime.now }
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

1. calling `build(:post, title: 'Post title', description: 'Post description')` will create a post object where only title and description are set (created_at will be nil)
2. calling `build(:post, :all_fields)` will create a post object will all fields set.

**Edit**

I think I understand the problem better now. Let's assume that this is you factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Post no. #{n}" }
    created_at { DateTime.now }
    description 'Post description'
  end
end
```

Change it to:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    transient do
      fields []
    end

    sequence(:title) { |n| "Post no. #{n}" }
    created_at { DateTime.now }
    description 'Post description'

    after :build do |post, evaluator|
      unless evaluator.fields.empty? do
        (post.attributes.keys - evaluator.fields).each do |attribute_to_remove|
          post.send("#{attribute_to_remove}=", nil)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, you can call it like this:

1. `build(:post)` creates post with all fields
2. `build(:post, fields: ['description', 'title'])` creates a post where everything except description and title is `nil`.

This solution should work as expected but it might slow down your tests (and I think it does not look nice :) )

Comment: Hi MrShemek. Traits are nice and I thought about this, the problem is that I cannot use it in this way. I have to be as consistent as the API call with the fields: [:field1, :field2, :etc...]

Comment: So my code will not work for you because object attributes are there (with the `nil` value) when they should not be accessible at all?

Comment: it works! but I've been demanded to add this param called fields and send an array with the fields you want

Comment: @Ruffeng please see my updated answer (part after `Edit`)

Comment: This new edit looks really good! Let my try it tomorrow morning at office and I‘ll let you know :)

Comment: I agree it does not look the best and can go slower. But it would really fit with the requirements i have

Comment: I have added `unless` statement. Otherwise when calling without `fields` attribute, it will set all fields to `nil`.

Comment: Sir, you deserve all my respects. This solution really worked for me. Glad you wanted to help me even if my request was weird :)

Answer (score 1):

FactoryBot lets you override the factory by passing a hash of attributes - so why not just set the attributes to nil:

```
build(:post, {
  title: nil,
  description: nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in FactoryBot is to have your standard factory produce objects that contain only the required fields for a model. (Note that FactoryBot will generate an `id` for you automatically.)

Assume you have a model called Post that requires only a `title`, but has optional fields `description` and `date`. Your factory would look like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title 'Post Title'
  end
end
```

Now when you build a Post, it will look like this:

```
>> FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:post)
#> <Post id: 1001, title: "Post Title", description: nil, date: nil>
```

You can add the optional fields on a case-by-case basis:

```
>> FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:post, description: 'This is a test post.')
#> <Post id: 1001, title: "Post Title", description: 'This is a test post.', date: nil>
```

Or you can add traits within the factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title 'Post Title'

    trait :with_description_and_date do
      description 'This is a test post.'
      date Date.today
    end
  end
end

>> FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:post, :with_description_and_date)
#> <Post id: 1001, title: "Post Title", description: 'This is a test post.', date: Thu, 12 Apr 2018>
```